# How do I prevent "return false;" in ajaxSubmit from conflicting with ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I must be missing something obvious...

I've got a standard ASP.NET MVC3 login Action that works as normal. If the user/password match then FormsAuthentication does its SetCookie routine and performs a RedirecToAction as expected or else it returns sets the model state error and returns the model back to the view. So this works with Javascript disabled.

I am now trying to add the jQuery.Form plugin to to do an ajaxSubmit and if the user does not use a matching user/password combo display the error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            success: showResponse
        };

        $('#formLogon').submit(function () {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
            // return false;
        });

        function showResponse() {
            $("#loginError").show();                             
        }
    });
```

My problem is that if I uncomment "return false;" after the ajaxSubmit the error div shows correctly when the showResponse function is called. However if a correct username/password is submitted the user is never redirected since the redirect is intercepted (but I have seen the GET call in Fiddler so I know the redirect is making the request).

I tried moving the "return false;" into the showResponse function but it doesn't work, without the return false after the ajaxSubmit the MVC redirects kick in before callback and the error div is never shown.

Is this not the correct implementation for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to look into the $.ajax function of jQuery. With this function you can define a callback.

What should happen is the following
On submit always return false
When a user enters a login make a ajax request.
if the user entered a correct login remove the submit functionality and make it submit using `$(this).submit`. (Using the callback of the $.ajax)
Then put the return false back.

It is a dirty fix but I think it would work

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following your sequence of events. Why submit the form again if I already submitted once and checked the password? And I'm not quite sure what you mean by "put the return false back."

Comment: Well what you are trying to do it to (realy) submit the form only when the login is correct. When you try to login you have the return false into the submit function. This makes the form only do a ajax call to the server and it doesn't submit because of the return false. If you use $.ajax you can define a callback function. In this callback function you can check if the login was correct or not. If it is not you can show the error, if it is correct you can remove the return false from the submit function of the login form. Then you let the form submit.